# django slugfield database error

Tags: django, django-models

I use django 1.4.

I am getting :

`DatabaseError at /
no such column: userside_post.slug`

Here, is my `model.py` :

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    text  = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

My `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('userside.views',
    url(r'^$','index'),
    url(r'^/(?P<postslug>_*)/$', 'userside.views.singlePost'),
)
```

My `views.py`:

```
def index(request):
    post_list = Post.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('userside/index.html',
                              {'post_list':post_list},
                              context_instance = RequestContext(request))

def singlePost(request,postslug):
    post = Post.objects.get(slug=postslug)
    context = {'post':post}
    return render_to_response('userside/detail.html',context,context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

and my Template file :

```
{% if post_list %}
    {% for x in post_list %}
        <p><a href="/{{ x.slug }}/">{{ x.title }}</a></p>
        <p>{{ x.text }}</p>
        <hr>
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    <div class="center">No records! ( but looks like code works correctly!)</div>
{% endif %}
```

and this is manage.py sql userside output :

```
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE "userside_post" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "title" varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    "text" text NOT NULL,
    "slug" varchar(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE
)
;
COMMIT;
```

but the PRAGMA table_info() OUTPUT IS :

```
0|id|integer|1||1
1|title|varchar(100)|1||0
2|text|text|1||0
```

What I am trying to do is, using slug on urls. sth-like-this

and last thing ;

I want prepopulated_fields for generate slugs automatically by posts title which, needs django admin.

But in my project I am not going to use django's admin. I am coding a new admin page.

What can I do for this ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check your database? You need to create `slug` field by running SQL query. To have an idea how your tables should look like run

```
python manage.py sql userside
```

From what I see in your question you should run following query in dbshell (this is for MySQL database)

```
ALTER TABLE userside_post ADD slug VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE;
```

Also I would suggest you to use [south](http://south.aeracode.org) for database migrations.

Comment: yes run sql command. even i re-create my table. but it is still same

Comment: did you check it with `DESCRIBE TABLE userside_post;`? Can you edit your question by adding output from that command as well as from `python manage.py sql userside`?

Comment: How did you "re-create" the table. Did you literally drop it, and then run CREATE TABLE again or simply run `syncdb`. If you run `syncdb` without dropping the table first, it *won't* recreate it or change it in any way.

Comment: i used 'sqlreset' command which drops table first ; and create table again.

Comment: @drTerminal also please add the output of `DESCRIBE TABLE userside_post;`. But run this command from `python manage.py dbshell`.

Comment: i added the output. btw its not mysql. it is sqlite3

Comment: @drTerminal See, you doesn't have `slug` field in your table

Comment: yea. i guess its caused by sqlite3. now i am gonna install postgresql. thank you